# Is the following sentence contrapositive of the sentence "If it's spring, the birds will sing"

Tags: logic, self-learning

I need to find the contrapositive, which is "If the birds do not sing, it is not spring"
But if it's written like, "If it's not spring, the birds will not sing", can this be considered contrapositive? If not, is this called negation of the original sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [inverse](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/converse-inverse-contrapositive#:%7E:text=To%20form%20the%20inverse%20of,they%20do%20not%20cancel%20school.%E2%80%9D&text=If%20the%20converse%20is%20true,inverse%20is%20also%20logically%20true.) of the statement.  I have to say, I learned this term in high school, nearly $60$ years ago, and I don't think I've ever heard it used since.

Comment: Wow, nice to know the name!

Comment: I don't know which answer to accept, both are helpful

Comment: Well, that's really up to you.

Comment: I'm accepting because you seemed to understand what I was asking :)

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive is 'If the birds do not sing, it is not spring.' ($\neg B \implies \neg A$)

The negation is 'It is spring and the birds will not sing.' ($A\wedge\neg B$)

'If it's not spring, the birds will not sing' is neither of these.

Comment: Thanks for the negation, it has increased my understanding of how to negate statements, so it'll help me in the future :)